# Get rid of L symbol (long datatype) in dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, long-integer, type-conversion

Given the following dictionary:

```
d={98558: [283L, 211L, 44L, 0L],
   98559: [283L, 212L, 44L, 1L],
   98560: [283L, 213L, 44L, 2L]}
```

I want to get rid of the `L` symbol using dict comprehension. My two solutions do not work:

1. `dmap={k: map(int, v[i]) for v in d.values() for i in v}`
2. `dmap={k: int(v[i]) for v in d.values() for i in v}`

They both return: `IndexError: list index out of range`, saying that `i=7L`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "L" is not actually part of the data. Python just prints that when displaying a long value so that you can see it is a long value. Internally, the value is just `7`. When you say "get rid of the L", are you really asking how to convert each long to an int? Is there a reason you can't use the long values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your comprehension `i` is an element of `v` and even if `v[i]` succeeds, **`v[i]` is a number, not a list**, so your first query cannot perform a `map`. Furthermore `k` is not defined (where does it originate from?).

In the second query, you associate an `int` with a key, but `k` is not defined anyway.

You can easily solve it like:

```
dmap = { k: map(int,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() }
```

Or you can write *list comprehension* yourself, like:

```
dmap = { k: [int(vi) for vi in v] for k,v in d.iteritems() }
```

Comment: So this way you are essentially taking each list as an element of its own and applying the `int` mapping to its entirety? I thought one had to apply the `int` operator to all elements individually, and with elements I mean the very numbers.

Comment: @FaCoffee: that is what a `map` basically does: it **maps** a list of `x`s to `f(x)`s.

Comment: All right, the list comprehension solution is the one I was trying to write. But thanks for showing a shorter one liner.